# Method Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin

Tags: javascript, meteor

Something seems to be wrong with the method. The code inside the method worked just fine when "insecure" was installed. Thanks!

`Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000" from accessing a frame with origin "chrome-extension://oknpjjbmpnndlpmnhmekjpocelpnlfdi".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "chrome-extension". Protocols must match.`

**Template Event**

```
Template.docEdit.events({
    'click .remove': function(event, template) {
        var thisTag = String(this);
        Meteor.call('removeTag', template, thisTag);
    },
});
```

**Method**

```
Meteor.methods({
    removeTag: function(template, thisTag) {
        MyPix.update (
            template.data._id,
            { $pull: { 'metadata.tags': thisTag }}
        );
    }
})
```

**This did work with "insecure" added**

```
Template.docEdit.events({
    'click .remove': function(event, template) {
        var thisTag = String(this);
        MyPix.update (
            template.data._id,
            { $pull: { 'metadata.tags': thisTag }}
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I was passing the whole template. The method only needs the id.

**Template Event**

```
Template.docEdit.events({
    'click .remove': function(event, template) {
        var thisTag = String(this);
        var thisId = template.data._id; // assign id to var
        Meteor.call('removeTag', thisId, thisTag);
    },
});
```

**Method**

```
Meteor.methods({
    removeTag: function(thisId, thisTag) {
        MyPix.update (
            thisId,
            { $pull: { 'metadata.tags': thisTag }}
        );
    },
})
```